# Splitting ideals generated by prime numbers in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let $p\in \mathbb{Z}$ a prime such that $\left(\frac{-5}{p}\right)=1$. Then as
$$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]/(p)\cong \mathbb{Z}[X]/(X^2+5)/(p)\cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X^2+5),$$
we have some $a$ such that $(X-a)(X+a)=X^2+5$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. Then by Chinese remainder theorem,
$$\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]/(p)\cong \mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X+a)\times\mathbb{F}_p[X]/(X-a)$$
How does this imply $(p)=(p, \sqrt{-5}+a)(p, \sqrt{-5}-a)$? This might be a trivial question, but I am really confused. I tried to find similar questions, but I failed to understand the rationale behind this immediate inference. I couldn't see why the isomorphic relation suggests that $(p)$ is a product of two ideals.

Comment: What is $A$? Is it $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$?

Comment: @Qwertiops Yes it is. I apologize for that. The post is edited.

Comment: How much other theory do you know about number fields? Can you use unique factorisation into ideals and related properties?

Comment: @Qwertiops Yes I can. But I don't see how that is related to the fact that we can infer $(p)$ can be split into two ideals generated by two elements.

Comment: An often useful fact is that if $f:R\to S$ is a homomorphism of commutative rings and $\mathfrak{p}$ is a prime ideal of $S$, then $f^{-1}(\mathfrak{p})$ is a prime ideal of $R$. Indeed, a lot of algebraic geometry depends on this. Anyway, here $R=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$, $S=\Bbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+5)$, and you have found two prime ideals of $S$. Checking their product is straight forward once you describe generators for the two prime ideals of $R$ you got.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This argument might be somewhat overcomplicated (and/or wrong), but I've written it now so I might as well post. I think sometimes the details of this sort of thing are glossed over, so it's possible this is what the author intended. It is also possible that I'm just an idiot.

**Answer:** If $R$ is a ring and $P$ is an ideal, then $P$ is prime if and only if $R/P$ is an integral domain. Therefore $(p)$ is not prime, so it must factor as a product of other prime ideals. The norm of $(p)$ is $p^2$, so it has two prime factors $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ of norm $p$.

Let $A, B$ be the images of $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ under the natural isomorphism

$$\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}] \to \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5).$$

Note that $p\in \mathfrak{a},\mathfrak{b}$ so $p \in A,B$. Therefore we may reduce mod $p$ to obtain ideals $\bar{A}, \bar{B}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+5)$ with $\bar{A}\bar{B} = 0$. These ideals lift to ideals $\tilde{A},\tilde{B}$ of $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ with $\tilde{A}\tilde{B} = (x^2+5)$, so by unique factorisation in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$, we have (without loss of generality) $\tilde{A} = (x+\sqrt{-5}),\tilde{B} = (x-\sqrt{-5})$, where we take the square root of $-5$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Therefore $\bar{A} = (x+\sqrt{-5})$ and $\bar{B} = (x-\sqrt{-5})$ modulo the ideal $(x^2+5)$. Lifting to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)$, we see that $A = (p, x+\sqrt{-5})$ and $B=(p, x-\sqrt{-5})$, and therefore we are done, because your $a$ is the same thing as my $\sqrt{-5}$.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the sentence "lifting to $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)$, we see that $A=(p, x+\sqrt{-5})$"? Does this mean, under the surjection $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2+5)\to \mathbb{F}_p[x]/(x^2+5)$, the preimage of $\bar{A}$ and $\bar{B}$ are $(p, x\pm\sqrt{-5})$?

Comment: @GoogleME yes that’s what I mean.

Comment: This is a super clear and concise answer. Thank you.